# I want to send email based upon a pandas column

Tags: python, email, smtplib

```
df1 = {'loc': ['blr', 'del','che'], 'name': ['abc', 'xyz','def']}

df2 = {'loc': ['blr', 'del','che'], 'balance': ['30', '40','20']}
```

I want to send emails from python. For every `loc` in `df2`, the `df2` part containing that location and balance needs to go to respective name in `df1`.

Currently, I am using smtpblib to send it, but the entire data is sent to everyone by attaching the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked on sending Automated emails, But merging data like below help you handle data better for your work:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(df2)
df=pd.merge(df1,df2, on='loc')
df
  loc name balance
0  blr  abc      30
1  del  xyz      40
2  che  def      20
```